# Configuring travis with parallel test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

I've been struggling for most of the day to set up travis with parallel_tests, and am unable to understand why it isn't working.

```
# .travis.yml
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.2.2
env:
  - DB=postgresql
cache: bundler
addons:
  postgresql: "9.4"
services:
  - postgresql
  - redis
script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake teaspoon
  - RAILS_ENV=test xvfb-run -a bundle exec rake parallel:spec
before_script:
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - cp config/database.travis.yml config/database.yml
  - export PARALLEL_TEST_PROCESSORS=4
  - RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:drop
  - RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:create
  - RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:migrate
  - bundle exec rake parallel:create
  - bundle exec rake parallel:prepare
```

My database.travis.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  database: adiq_dev
  pool: 25
  username: postgres
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  database: adiq_test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
  pool: 25
  username: postgres
  password:
```

On parallel prepare, I keep getting this

```
You have 174 pending migrations:

...
...

Run rake db:migrate to update your database then try again.
The command "bundle exec rake parallel:prepare" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

The exact chain of commands seems to work fine on my local
I don't get it, where am I going wrong?

Any suggestions will be invaluable....I have spent a lot of hours trying to make this work.

Comment: Try adding `rake db:migrate` between create and prepare steps, or after the prepare step

Answer (score 0):

The parallel:load_schema was the trick. Updated file...

```
# .travis.yml
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.2.2
env:
  - DB=postgresql
cache: bundler
addons:
  postgresql: "9.4"
services:
  - postgresql
  - mongodb
  - redis
script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake teaspoon
  - RAILS_ENV=test xvfb-run -a bundle exec rake parallel:spec
before_script:
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - cp config/database.travis.yml config/database.yml
  - cp config/mongoid.travis.yml config/mongoid.yml
  - export PARALLEL_TEST_PROCESSORS=4
  - RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
  - bundle exec rake parallel:create parallel:load_schema parallel:prepare
```